# Image handling in Python with Numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, ftp

We are importing an screen capture from a web page direct into a variable in Python; and then producing a Numpy array using the following code :

To capture is a PNG image (note - the device url has an embedded cgi to do the capture work) :

```
response = requests.get(url.format(ip, device), auth=credentials)
```

Once screen is captured, covert to a Numpy array called image :

```
image = imread(BytesIO(response.content))
```

After analysis of image, we would like to FTP the captured PNG to a server for reference at a later date.  The best solution we can find right now involves using imsave to create a file locally and then FTP with storbinary to take the local image and put it on the server.

Is it possible to FTP response.content; or a conversion of the numpy array back into a PNG (using imsave?) direct to the server and skip the local storage step?

### Update

As per MattDMo comment, we tried:

```
def ftp_artifact (ftp_ip, ftp_dir, tid, artifact_name, artifact_path, imgdata) :
   ftp = FTP(ftp_ip)
   ftp.login("autoftp","autoftp")
   ftp.mkd ("FTP/" + ftp_dir)
   ftp.cwd("FTP/" + ftp_dir)
   filepath = artifact_path
   filename = artifact_name
   f = BytesIO(imgdata)
   ftp.storbinary ('STOR ' + filename, f)
   ftp.quit()
```

Where imgdata is the result of io.imread.  The result file is 5x bigger and not an image.  The BytesIO object is the numpy array I presume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit of research but our student figured it out :

```
def ftp_image_to(ftp_ip, ftp_dir, filename, data):
    ftp = FTP(ftp_ip)
    print("logging in")
    ftp.login('autoftp', 'autoftp')
    print("making dir")
    ftp.mkd('FTP/' + ftp_dir)
    ftp.cwd('FTP/' + ftp_dir)
    print("formatting image")
    bytes = BytesIO()
    plt.imsave(bytes, data, format='png')
    bytes.seek(0)
    print("storing binary")
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, bytes)
    ftp.quit()
```

Thanks IH!

Answer (score 1):

In the `ftplib` module, the [`FTP.storbinary()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) method takes an open file object as its second argument. Since your `BytesIO` object can act as a file object, all you'd need to do is pass that - no need for a temporary file on the server.

**EDIT**

Without seeing your full code, what I suspect is happening is that you are passing the NumPy array to `storbinary()`, not the `BytesIO` object. You also need to make sure the object's read pointer is at the beginning by calling `bytesio_object.seek(0)` before uploading. The following code demonstrates how to do everything:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO
import requests

r = requests.get("http://example.com/foo.png")
png = BytesIO(r.content)

# do image analysis

png.seek(0)
ftp = FTP("ftp.server.com")
ftp.login(user="username", passwd="password")
# change to desired upload directory
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file_name, png)
try:
    ftp.quit()
except:
    ftp.close()
```

Comment: I get where you are coming from, we tried however the BytesIO object is not an image,  We get a file but it is 5x bigger than the original image.

Comment: Edited main question to include attempt with MattDMo's suggestion.

Comment: @DanG please see my edit, hopefully it will solve your problem.